# How to save and use a user picked option in a dropdown list as a variable?

Tags: php, variables, submit, html-select

What I need to do is let the user pick in the dropdown list. Then when the user clicked submit, I will have an if..else statement that executes different codes depending on what the user picked in the dropdown list.

```
Shipping Provider: <select id='ship' name='ship'>
<option value="val1">Value1</option>
<option value="val2">Value2</option>
<option value="val3">Value3</option>
<option value="val4">Value4</option>
</select>
```

Then after that, I don't know on how to save it. What I'm thinking is like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['extract'])){

$dropdownvalue = $_POST['ship'];

if($dropdownvalue == 'Value1'){
       EXECUTE CODE HERE
}
else if($dropdownvalue == 'Value2'){
       EXECUTE CODE HERE
}
else if($dropdownvalue == 'Value3'){
       EXECUTE CODE HERE
}
else{
       EXECUTE CODE HERE
}
}
```

but somehow it's not working. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have set a value in the dropdown option it will be that value

change your code to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['extract'])){

 $dropdownvalue = $_POST['ship'];

 if($dropdownvalue === 'val1'){
   EXECUTE CODE HERE
 }
 else if($dropdownvalue === 'val2'){
   EXECUTE CODE HERE
 }
 else if($dropdownvalue === 'val3'){
   EXECUTE CODE HERE
 }
 else{
   EXECUTE CODE HERE
 }
}
```

**A little explantion**

When you use the value attribute on a option element the value attribtute will be used, this is also happing in your code. When you don't use a value attribute the string between the option element will be used.

so your html will look like this:

```
<option>string</option>
```

In php the value you will get is `string`. But when you used the value attribute you will be able to show a string that is not the same as the value you will be sending

your html looks like this:

```
<option value="1">String</option>
```

now the value you will get in php is `1`, this is very useful, and in my opion you should always use the value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

im not sure but doesnt you need to check for the option value like

```
if($dropdownvalue == 'val1'){
    ....
}
```

you can also, for debugging, echo the value of $dropdownvalue to see what value it actually has

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider making use of switch case in this case

```
if(isset($_POST['extract'])){
    if(isset($_POST['ship'] and !empty($_POST['ship'])){
        $dropdownvalue = $_POST['ship'];
        switch($dropdownvalue){
            case 'val1' : 
                // Code here
                break;
            case 'val2' :
                // Code here
                break;                
            case 'val3' :
                // Code here
                break;            
            case 'val4' :
                // Code here
                break;            
            default : 
                // Code here            
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have value of the selected option not the text.

```
if(isset($_POST['extract'])){

    $dropdownvalue = $_POST['ship'];

    if($dropdownvalue == 'val1'){
           EXECUTE CODE HERE
    }
    else if($dropdownvalue == 'val2'){
           EXECUTE CODE HERE
    }
    else if($dropdownvalue == 'val3'){
           EXECUTE CODE HERE
    }
    else{
           EXECUTE CODE HERE
     }
   }
```